# Enable adb shell auto-completion in archlinux

Tags: shell, autocomplete, adb, archlinux

The auto-completion with <kbd>Tab</kbd> is not working in an `adb shell` on archlinux. 
Everything else is working fine. Do you know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is auto completion with <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is managed by the shell you're running, as a built-in. It is your shell (let's say Bash) that decides what to do when this key is pressed.

Once you've left Bash, it no longer applies and that behavior is determined by the program running, which here, is `adb` and its own shell program that probably does not include a real user friendly list of features.

Comment: I forgot to say that adb shell auto-completion is fully working in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same, `bash-completion` package will provide completions for that.

```
sudo pacman -S bash-completion
```